# Core Data tutorial on apple Dev will not work?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data

i tried multiple times to do the core data tutorial for IOS on developer.apple.com and i cannot get the app to work!:( i copied and pasted the code and did everything exactly as the tutorial said! But however, in the tutorial, it says after a few seconds that the `addButton` will become active after a few seconds. But it doesnt. So i got ride of a few lines of code that set the `enabled` property to no so that way the button is active. But when i press the button now, its supposed to add cells with my current location, however, it does nothing! Please help!! Thanks so much!

Here is the site for the tutorial!:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/04_Adding.html

Comment: Kind of impossible to guess what you did wrong - missing too much information (like e.g. the source code).

Comment: well.. its just the code off of the site! lol umm... what do you suggest i post? THanks for the reply!

Comment: You have not even linked the sample you are referring to. Should we guess?

Comment: Oh im sorry! :/ ill post it in the question!

Comment: Did you run this on a real device or simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you start a new project and check Use core data? Also you would need to create a core data model object with an event type.

Comment: Yes i did both of those! i did EVERY step that the tutorial said and i did it 3 more times and still cant get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, that tutorial needs to be updated for Xcode 4 and iOS 6.

Here is the code of the tutorial updated for Xcode 4, with some instructions:
https://github.com/arielelkin/Locations